# IE 11 onload is never called

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

My web page has following javascript

```
function LoadPDF(filename)
{
    var loc = filename;
    document.getElementById("pdf").setAttribute("src", loc);
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById("pdf").addEventListener("load", LoadPrint, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        document.getElementById("pdf").attachEvent("onload", LoadPrint);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("pdf").onload = LoadPrint;
    }
}

function LoadPrint() {
    alert('fired!');
    if (document.getElementById("pdf").src !== "") {
       var frm = document.getElementById("pdf");        
       frm.contentDocument.getElementById("pdf").contentWindow.print();
    }
}
```

The LoadPDF is called from code behind. "pdf" is my iframe. When the pdf is loaded into the iframe I want to call LoadPrint. But the trouble is in IE 11 its never called.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: When is it supposed to get called? This is only the definition

Comment: is it working on all other browsers? do you get an error on IE or it just doesn't work?

Comment: Yes this is only IE specific. Works on all other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an IE11 [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809377/ie-11-load-event-doesnt-fired-for-pdf-in-iframe), which MS refuses to fix because they consider it a feature bug and they no longer fix that kind of bugs for old browser versions.

A workaround to this bug, is to load the pdf file inside an other page iframe and then load that page inside your iframe. A simple javascript pdf loader with a file argument:

```javascript
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PDF Loader</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

#pdf {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="pdf"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var pdf = getParameterByName('pdf');
document.getElementById('pdf').setAttribute('src', pdf);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use it with the `<filename.html>?pdf=<pdf_file_to_load>`.

Then you just change your code to load the pdf file through that loader like this:

```
function LoadPDF(filename)
{
    var loc = "pdf-loader.html?pdf="+filename;
    document.getElementById("pdf").setAttribute("src", loc);
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById("pdf").addEventListener("load", LoadPrint, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        document.getElementById("pdf").attachEvent("onload", LoadPrint);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("pdf").onload = LoadPrint;
    }
}

function LoadPrint() {
    alert('fired!');
}

LoadPDF('http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf');
```

Now the `LoadPrint` function is called on iframe load event even on IE11.
Here is my working example you can even test with IE11: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/ie11-iframe-pdf/

Here you can see a screen capture with the 10MB PDF loading and only after it finish loading it fires the `load` event and alerts the message:

[image]

Comment: I don't see your example working. As soon as I open the page in IE11, the 'fired' alert opens before the pdf is loaded

Comment: @user2837961 because the PDF does not show up, that does not mean it's not loaded. I have added a pdf url with a file of 10MB size on the same link. Try to reload the link and you will see that the browser actually takes some time to load that 10MB PDF before it fires the `load` event and alert the "fired" message; That's because all that time waits to load all of the data of that large PDF.

Comment: its strange but I get 'fired' and soon as I click on the link and then pdf takes time to load/ show

Comment: @user2837961 I have updated my answer with a screen capture that shows the behavior I'm talking about. You can see clearly that it does not popup the alert message before the PDF finish loading. Did you clear IE11 cache before you load the page?

Comment: Thanks this works. After the 'fired' I want to print the pdf. Could you please help me with that? I have updated my question but gives 'Invalid calling object' error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your specific issue in this instance, but make sure you bind your listeners to the element before you assign it's src attribute. If the item is in cache it is possible for the load event to fire before you bind to it, thus missing it entirely.

Comment: I tried loading the src after assigning the event but does not work

Comment: @user2837961 I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Are there any errors being dumped to the console?

Comment: Nothing in console unfortunately